# QGIS reprojecting .ecw file in EPSG:23032

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ecw

I opened the .ecw file with qgis but I found that the ortophoto is 340 mt northern and 150 mt eastern the topographic map. How can I move the ecw?

Comment: Can you add the projection definition of the ecw file?

Comment: EPSG:23032-ED50 UTM zone 32N, the same as the topographic raster...

Comment: Does it fit better if you change the CRS of one or the other layer to WGS84 UTM 32N?

Comment: A little better but the offset remains...

Comment: no great I changed just one and it does work!!!!

Comment: than you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If both layers are UTM and do not align, there is a chance that they don't share the same datum.

So one can be ED50 UTM 32N, and the other WGS84 UTM 32N.

In this case, `Rightclick -> Set CRS for Layer` is the right tool to change one layer or the other (but not both, because then they will both end up shifted, but not relative to each other).